# Auto scaling with ECS losing services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We have a situation where we have 6 services deployed across 3 EC2 instances with autoscaling enabled.

When our load is increasing a new EC2 instance is getting added with some services on it, and when a load is less on one of the services then EC2 is scaling down.

This leads to stopping another service, what could be the solution to this?

We are looking for AWS Fargate option. But without that can we implement it?

Comment: Are you using ECS in this solution at the moment?

Comment: yes @mokugo-devops

Answer (score 2):

Under the assumption you're using Amazon ECS the only suggestion I could add is that you take a look at running your services using [Dynamic Ports](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/) if that's possible.

By using Dynamic Hosts you can run multiple tasks of the same service on the same host.

You can configure a combination of autoscaling on the EC2 hosts, as well as [autoscaling on the service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html) itself. However, bare in mind that when you initially boot up a host it may not have a service deployed initially.

As you pointed out Fargate would be an option for this which in my opinion will simplify your scaling issues.

If you do choose to use Fargate take a look at using [savings plans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/savings-plans.html) to reduce your costs.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the primary advantages of having an [application load balancer paired with your ECS service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html). When tasks are started, they are added to the ALB and will start receiving traffic once they become healthy. As tasks start to be killed off, ECS intelligently puts the task into `draining` on the ALB, waits for the ALB to confirm the target has been removed (which happens once draining is complete), and will *then* shutdown the task. This allows existing requests to complete while preventing new requests from reaching the tasks that are shutting down.